# Opencv libraries have prblems

Tags: c++, c, opencv, libraries

I've just installed today opencv in my computer and configure it for microsoft visual studio. I created a little program that access my camera, only that. In my computer it worked perfectly, however, I wanted to prove it in other computer to see if it worked, but it said me that it was unable to execute the program because it didn't find the library opencv_world451.lib. Does someone knows how can I execute that program without installing opencv, or that library?

Comment: ***Does someone knows how can I execute that program without installing opencv, or that library?*** Just copy the resulting executable and dlls from the Release folder to a USB stick and run them on the other PC without Visual Studio. Depending on where you put your opencv dlls you may have to copy them. Also you may need to install the microsoft redistributable for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit confused by your question because you say you are trying to run the program and it is complaining about a missing .lib file.  Normally on Windows (assumed because you say Visual Studio) .lib files are used during compilation, which suggests you are trying to compile and link the program before running it on the second computer.

You should be able to build a Release build on your first computer and copy the .exe across to the second computer IF you are not changing the source code on the 2nd machine.

If you are building the code on PC2 then you will need to install the libraries on that PC too.

The program still may not run if the exe requires some OpenCV DLLs, if this is the case there may be some instructions for creating or deploying a redistributable package in the help pages.